# Dynamic content of Web Page not loaded totally using Htmlunit WebClient

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I am trying to load web page (https://genpact.taleo.net/careersection/sgy_external_career_section/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en) for scraping using HtmlUnit WebClient. But the content is not being loaded properly. For example, i am unable to find the Apply buttons.
My webclient code is as below

```
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new DefaultCssErrorHandler());
        webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener());
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
```

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    final String url = "https://genpact.taleo.net/careersection/sgy_external_career_section/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

        // waitForBackgroundJavaScript has to be called after every action
        // this page is really slow wait for the last part of the dynamic content
        while(!page.asText().contains("Previous\r\n1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n")) {
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1_000);
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(page.asText());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```